# If $\delta$ is a subbase of a $T_1$ space $X$ with at least two points, then $\cup\delta= X$

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

Am reading about subbases on Wikipedia, where a distinction is made if a subbase $\delta$ covers the space $X$ or not. In the former case we don't need the nullary intersection convention $\cap \emptyset =X$ to obtain a basis from the collection of all finite intersections of elements of $\delta$ (nonempty finite intersections are sufficient).

One can then read: "a subbase of a space that has at least two points and satisfies the $T_1$ separation axiom must be a cover of that space." Am trying to prove this fact:

Suppose on the contrary that $\delta$ is a subbasis for some $T_1$ space $(X,\tau)$ containing two distinct elements and $\cup \delta\neq X$. Let $\nu$ denote the subspace topology on $Y:=\cup \delta$. We check that $\{X\}\cup \nu$ is the smallest topology on $X$ containing $\nu$. Since $\delta\subset\nu\subset\tau$, this topology in turn coincide with $\tau$, and so $\{X\}\cup \nu=\tau$. But then the only neighborhood of any point  $x\in X\setminus Y$ is $X$ itself, which contradicts the $T_1$ assumption.

Am I missing something?

Comment: No, I don't think you are missing anything. Your argument looks good to me.

Comment: @RobArthan Thanks a lot for your feedback.